# poor performance of workers in foreach package of R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am working with foreach and doParallel package in Windows, but the CPU used in the code is less than 10% during the foreach function. This is the code that I use with a small example.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)
library(Matrix)
cl <- detectCores() - 1  
registerDoParallel(cl)
n_max=1300000
df=data.frame(fromID=sample(c(1:1300000),2000,replace=TRUE),
              toID=sample(c(1:1300000),2000,replace=TRUE),
              group=sample(c(1:10),2000,replace=TRUE))
As=foreach (i=1:10,.packages=c('dplyr','Matrix'))%dopar%{
  databygroup=filter(df,group==i)
        sparseMatrix(i=databygroup$fromID,j=databygroup$toID,x=1,dims=c(n_max,n_max))
}  

stopImplicitCluster()
```

Before using the foreach, I have this result to know how many workers are active.

```
> cat(sprintf('%s backend is registered\n',
+             if(getDoParRegistered()) 'A' else 'No'))
A backend is registered
> cat(sprintf('Running with %d worker(s)\n', getDoParWorkers()))
Running with 35 worker(s)
> (name <- getDoParName())
[1] "doParallelSNOW"
> (ver <- getDoParVersion())
[1] "1.0.11"
> if (getDoParRegistered())
+   cat(sprintf('Currently using %s [%s]\n', name, ver))
Currently using doParallelSNOW [1.0.11]
```

The message that I received is this for several connections

"In if (.Internal(exists(package, .Internal(getNamespaceRegistry()),  ... :
  closing unused connection 70..."

And after using "stopImplicitCluster" function, the number of workers is the same. So, I am not able to close the workers.

stopCluster(cl) doesn´t work

```
> cat(sprintf('Running with %d worker(s)\n', getDoParWorkers()))
Running with 2 worker(s)
> (name <- getDoParName())
[1] "doParallelSNOW"
> (ver <- getDoParVersion())
[1] "1.0.11"
> if (getDoParRegistered())
+ cat(sprintf('Currently using %s [%s]\n', name, ver))
Currently using doParallelSNOW [1.0.11]
> stopCluster(cl)
> cat(sprintf('Running with %d worker(s)\n', getDoParWorkers()))
Running with 2 worker(s)
> stopCluster(cl)
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

I don´t know why the parallelization is not working.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Use `parallel::stopCluster(cl)` to kill workers.

Comment: It is not working. I write the code above in the question

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but the problem is that the computer takes a lot of time among tasks. That's why the used CPU is so low.